# Split a csv file into chunk to import with phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

I need to import a csv file via phpMyAdmin but it is larger than 2MB.

I have already read the answers :

- Use mysql server < file.csv
- Increase the size of the upload file in the mysql config.

I can't use the mysql because I don't have a direct access to the server and currently I can't change the configuration.

My question is : Do you know a program that split (correctly) a csv file in chunks ?
Favorite language is Java but I will check other solutions.

Comment: Do you want to load CSV-file to one BLOB cell, or to load all data from the file into many rows/many columns?

Comment: many colums and one of them is a xml type (mediumtext). So they are newline in the csv file (for 1 row) because of the data. I need a program that "understand" the csv structure and split it correctly. They are also many rows.

Comment: So, you may need to use LOAD DATA INFILE command - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: Yes but as I said I don't have access to this server. I have also tried to access from another server. But the command was rejected. Administror is good in security :) So my only access so far is via phpMyAdmin. Thx.

Comment: LOAD DATA INFILE is MySQL command, you can execute it from phpMyAdmin. ...check if you have FILE privilege.